# Reconfigure Existing Providers in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, currency-exchange-rates

In the configure exchange rate providers form I have removed the existing providers and they are also removed in their coresponding tables so when I press the add button it shows me the error that could not find the providers.How can I add them back.The corresponding classes for ax and .NET providers exist.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question, but if clicking "Add" gives you an error, it's probably just environment issues and you need to bounce the AOS, datbase sync, full compile, and CIL compile and it'll probably resolve the issue.

It determines the list of exchange rate providers to display in this method:
`\Classes\ExchangeRateProviderRegistration\initialize`

Comment: I restarted the AOS ,synchronized the database but it still shows me this:ExchangeRateProvider object not initialized.

Stack trace

(C)\Classes\ExchangeRateProviderRegistration\searchForAxProviders - line 21
(C)\Classes\ExchangeRateProviderRegistration\initialize - line 14
(C)\Classes\ExchangeRateProviderRegistration\new - line 3
(C)\Classes\ExchangeRateProviderRegistration\construct - line 3
(C)\Forms\ExchangeRateProviderLookup\Methods\init - line 5
(C)\Classes\SysSetupFormRun\init - line 3
(C)\Classes\FormDropDialogButtonControl\Clicked

Comment: Well these are .NET assemblies, did you do a full CIL compile? This isn't a programming question and it specific to your environment. Look at the code in the method I referenced and you'll see that it's calling a .NET assembly.

Comment: The remake of incremental CIL and a database sync solved the issue

Comment: Glad I could help.